# Breaking and resuming in the middle of a function?

Tags: python

I am working on my final programming project and am attempting to create battleship. The only thing I have to do yet is to program the automatic intelligence. The way it works so far is by guessing two random integers from 1 to 11 to pick a random space on the grid. Once it hits something, I have rules created so that it will check on all sides until it has sunk an entire ship. The issue with this, is that then the computer will take like eight turns at a time. I need to somehow jump out of the function, back to my main run function, then resume where it left off for the next turn. Is there a way to do this, or would there be a better and entirely different way to take turns?

This is what my turns function currently looks like. The user_guess function works fine, then it checks to see if you have won the game. thinking() is purely aesthetic, then I get to the comp_guess function which I have questions about, then it checks to see if you have lost. Then it recalls itself.

```
    def turns():
        user_guess()
        if win_game==True:
            return ('YOU WIN!')
        thinking()
        comp_guess()
        if lose_game==True:
            return ('YOU LOSE!')
        turns()
```

Then so far, all I have for my comp_guess function is:

```
    def comp_guess():
        comp_in1=random.randrange(1,11)
        comp_in2=random.randrange(1,11)
        if (grid_two[comp_in1])[comp_in2]=='S':
            (grid_two[comp_in1])[comp_in2]='X'
            (grid_four[comp_in1])[comp_in2]='X'
        else:
            (grid_two[comp_in1])[comp_in2]='*'
            (grid_four[comp_in1])[comp_in2]='*'
        for f in grid_four:
            print(' '.join(f))
```

grid_two is a stored grid of all the ship locations. grid_four is the one that gets displayed and it just keeps track of the computers moves and whether they were hit or misses.

Comment: A specific example of what you have done so far would help us answer your question much better.  However, you should probably have a function that chooses a single space based on some input logic/state.  Then call this function as many times as needed in another function that controls the flow of the program.

Comment: I'm afraid this will be closed, maybe you want to show the outline of the program you have. Just to jump in before: You need to store state between moves, even without your logic - otherwise you'd never know which fields you've already fired at. Insert that into the overall design of your program and you'll know where to store the information about having hit something as well. If you're unsure about how to structure that, that would make for a more specific question, that, along with code samples, is probably easier to answer here

Comment: Based on a cursory scan of your question, it sounds like you want a *coroutine*. Python generators can be implemented as coroutines. [Read up for details](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to loop a random int until it finds a slot that is not already taken.
Set if statements so the computer can tell if it has hit a ship or not.
After that it should go back to the main function.
```

I think the reason the computer is taking more than 1 turn is because it is looping until it kills a ship?
The main loop that swaps from player goes, should have a condition that ends the game.